# What is hostname in terminal prompt?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

My mac terminal prompt is:

```
wbk-er-10-132-118-162:~ johnjara$
```

I did `echo $PS1` and got `\h:\W \u\$`, which would be the hostname: the basename of $PWD, my username, respectively. My  computer name in System Preferences > Sharing is Copper's Macbook Pro.

So what is `\h` here for my Mac if not computer name? How do I change it? 
 Also, why my IP address would be there in hostname?

Comment: What is the computer name in System Preferences > Sharing?

Comment: You could do an `echo $PS1` and match the codes with meanings here: https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html and then try to figure out yourself. Numbers are definitely IP. And Steve might be right too about Computer name. See ~/.bash_profile file too. It's hidden, (notify me by @ankiiiiiii)

Comment: My cpu name is Copper's Macbook Pro. @ankiiiiiii I did echo $PS1 and got \h:\W \u\$ which would be the hostname, the basename of $PWD, and my username, respectively. Do either of you know why my IP address would be showing?

Comment: Here's an even closer duplicate (where the IP address is included in the name): [MacOS Strange Terminal Prompt, Tried Resetting Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal/).